# HTML5 Video OGV conversion on Mac

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg, oggvorbis, ogg-theora

When I try recording a screencast with Quicktime or Screenflow and then converting to .ogv for use on the web, I get this error many times:

```
$ ffmpeg2theora test.mov
[audioresample @ 0x7fa903800ee0] Audio sample format conversion failed
```

The resulting `test.ogv` file does not play in VLC. I can use `ffmpeg` to successfully convert mov to mp4. Are there only certain audio types that `ffmpeg2theora` supports? ffmpeg2theora version 0.29

More output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2013-08-26 20:50:37
  Duration: 00:00:07.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1458 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 90 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-26 20:50:37
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1200, 1362 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 3k tbn, 6k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-08-26 20:50:37
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

Comment: Does `ffmpeg2theora` have additional features missing in `ffmpeg`? Why not just use `ffmpeg` to make ogv? `ffmpeg -i input -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis -q:v 7 -q:a 5 output.ogv` See [FFmpeg Wiki: Theora and Vorbis Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
brew remove ffmpeg
brew install --with-theora --with-libvorbis ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i test.mov -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis -q:v 10 -q:a 10 test.ogv
```

Comment: `-c:v theora` may work, depending on your ffmpeg version, but it's more typical to be explicit in encoder names, so it should be changed to `-c:v libtheora`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be specifically interested in ffmpeg solution, but the [Miro Video Convertor](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) is another free OS X option that works great for converting mov to ogg.